Spin_texture using quantum espresso
I'm working with Quantum ESPRESSO and currently trying to plot the spin texture from my Bands.x calculation. The output file provides the spin projections for each k-point, but I’m unsure how to format the data for plotting.
Specifically, I want to organize the data into a format where each row contains the k-point coordinates (kx,ky,kz) and their corresponding spin projections(sx,sy,sz).
​The goal is to have a file with the following columns:
k_x   k_y   k_z   S_x   S_y   S_z
Has anyone done this before, or can anyone provide guidance on how to extract and format the data for plotting?
Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated!
